# Separating two label names in QGIS in order of having a better display

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am working with layers that have several characteristics in the attributable, and I need to show two of them together. 
Here is a demo map of the US state that shows me problem.

I used the string connection functions in the expression dialog for the simultaneous displaying of the "postal" and the "name" labels. [image]

Now this two labels are displaying together as one word. I tried to separate the "postal" from the "name" by enlarging the word values, but it's only separate the label that have to words in it. [image]

I have tried to  change the placement of the labels, but they all moved as one word. [image]

How can I separate this two labels?

In this demo map example I need to separate the "ND" from the "North Dakota".[image]

Comment: What about `"name" + ' ' + "postal"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comment from [Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25814/joseph) the problem is solved.

I have right the concatenating functions with an empty expression ' ' and + mark between the words. [image]

The result is separation of the labels as I needed it to be.

[image]

Comment: Careful, it's ' ', not " "

Comment: Maybe it's quibbling but you are rather 'concatenating' than 'aggregating' compared to existing function/expression names. Just to prevent any misunderstandings...