# Changing the label color with the Expression Dialog in QGIS 3.4.1

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to [separate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252726/separating-two-label-names-in-qgis-in-order-of-having-a-better-display) two labels and then coloring each one separately, using QGIS 3.4.1.
So, I was trying to color a label within the Expression Dialog.
However, I could not figure out how to wright the function.

[image]

I tried all the Color function, but it did not worked.
The color's name was taken from the "Select Text Color" within the "layer Styling" bar and it a shade of green that supposed to replace the red.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible what you want to achieve because you cannot set different colors for different text parts of one label in QGIS. But there are workarounds to get similar results which might be interesting for you. Take a look at the following links: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242864/multi-labeling-with-multiple-colours-in-qgis or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195848/assigning-different-colors-to-different-parts-of-text-in-labels-using-qgis/210737

Answer (score 3):

You can set a label color using expressions, but not in the label value field.
You need to use the datadefined override for the color selector.

Example:

```
if( "Attribute_name" = 'value', '#FF0000', '#000000')
```

The above expression sets the color to red if true and black if false.

To help you build your expression you can also use the "Assistant..." when clicking on the datadefined override button to the right of the color selector.